# Clone and set value for data-name

Tags: jquery

Trying to clone a select drop down box and add an extra random data-name value.

In all my tests it is not working. Anyone know how to this in the one-liner below?

This part works smooth:

```
$('.copy').on('click', function () {
    var cloneId = $(this).attr('data-name');
    $(".clone-"+cloneId).clone().insertAfter(".clone-"+cloneId+":last").removeClass('clone-'+cloneId).removeProp('required');
});
```

Here, at the end I am trying to change the data-name. This part doesn't work.

```
$('.copy').on('click', function () {
    var cloneId = $(this).attr('data-name');
    $(".clone-"+cloneId).clone().insertAfter(".clone-"+cloneId+":last").removeClass('clone-'+cloneId).removeProp('required').attr("data-name", ''+cloneId+'-333');
});
```

Where '-333' should be a random number.

**UPDATE:**
This is running now, but still figuring out the random one for each item cloned when 'on click'.

```
   $('.copy').on('click', function () {
        var cloneId = $(this).attr('data-name');
        var cloneFull = $(".clone-"+cloneId).attr('id');
        randomValue = parseInt(Math.random()*999999,10);


        $(".clone-"+cloneId).clone().insertAfter(".clone-"+cloneId+":last").removeClass('clone-'+cloneId).prop('required', false).attr("name", cloneFull + '-' + randomValue);

    });
```

Comment: You shouldn't remove native properties. Just set it to `false` (*`.prop('required', false)`*). Also use `Math.random()` for the random part

Comment: That is sort of not an option :-) We are using it to store the data in the database. Do you perhaps know how to make it work?

Comment: which part does not work ? the setting of the `data-name` attribute ? do you get an error ?

Comment: Doesn't work and no error as well. Thanks for the .prop-tip! Already changed it and its working!

Comment: Seems to work at https://jsfiddle.net/2t3e1nf2/ (*use debug tools to see the actual attribute*) (*uses 0-1000 random values*)

Comment: Thanks so much for this quick response! It works like a charm and the inserts in the database are flawless now! Super thanks Gaby!

Comment: keep in mind that the numbers are not guaranteed to be unique (*just random*)

Comment: Yes, thanks! Changed it to a 6-digit nr. This extra value is only used to generate unique POSTS for dBase inserts. Now they all clear. The odds for an error are almost 0 now. The clone will be made max 4 times.

Comment: Update: the unique random value is not working with multiple clones at once. Working on it :-)

Comment: you will have to generate the random value inside your *loop*

Comment: Working on it but no success as of yet. Studying on this is nice, but rather have some results. :-)

Comment: could you post some code ?

Comment: added the updated code without my previous errors, but still looking for the unique add-on id for each item populated onClick. All cool stuff, but a little above my level as of yet,

Comment: ps. also working on it with your coding as well :-)

Comment: so, `$(".clone-"+cloneId)` returns multiple elements ?

Comment: Yep. multiple select drop-downs actually. And I only need a unique nr for each item as an add on to its attr.

Comment: Never thought this would be so tricky! But a brain teaser it is, and I've tried all the uniques etc. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: I see that you use `.attr('id');` which means on the `$(".clone-"+cloneId)`. This implies that many elements share the same `id` and that is invalid in html. (*might cause problems if you try to select by id in the future*)

Comment: That is actually the same one, but thanks for this as well. I'll have a look at it tomorrow- seriously night time in Holland here! Thanks so far Gaby! ...oops...you've just posted an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will handle the original issue (*with the random value*) as well as the expanded issue of the multiple elements that need their own unique random numbers.

```
$('.copy').on('click', function () {
    var initialName= $(this).attr('data-name'),
        className = "clone-" + initialName,
        elements = $('.' + className);


    elements
        .clone()
        .insertAfter(elements.last())
        .removeClass(className)
        .prop('required', false)
        .attr("name", function(i,v){ // use the version that runs a function for each element in the group. You could have used .each as an alternative.
                var randomValue = parseInt(Math.random()*999999,10),
                    actualId = this.id; // moved the id retrieval in the loop as i think you want the id of each element to be used.
                return actualId + '-' + randomValue;
            });
});
```

Updated demo at https://jsfiddle.net/2t3e1nf2/1/

I have cached the `$(".clone-"+cloneId)` part in a variable to improve performance and clarity. I have also renamed some variables for legibility (*on my part, so you can change them to whatever again*)

Comment: You are too cool! I'll run it during first coffee in Holland 8am. Thanks man!

Comment: Truly awsome this one! Thank you so much for fixing my problem! Great study for me as well! Thanks again!